# Canvasexpress : pass a variable as a property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam using this library :

http://canvasxpress.org/scatter2d.html

now I was trying to build a Scatter2D chart , using the following code:

```
var showDemo2 = function (chartrows,chartvars,chartdata,colors,color) {
          $("#c2").show()
          $("#c1").hide()

       cx2 = new CanvasXpress('canvas2',
          {

            'y' : {
              'vars' : chartrows,
              'smps' : chartvars,
              'data' : chartdata,

            },
             'z' : {
              'color' : colors,

            },

          },
          {
          'graphType': 'Scatter2D',
            "colorBy":'color',
          'xAxis': [chartvars[0]],
          'yAxis': [chartvars[1]]}
        );



      }
```

This works fine , but the problem is the 'z' , whenever i try to pass a variable , the code automatically stringifies it , for example if 'z' was as :

```
'z' : {
              somevariable : colors,

            }
```

the 'somevariable' is still passed as a string , i have the minified code , and it is very hard to find the part where the original dev stringifies the property , any solution to bypass the string conversion ? tried eval() but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

after inspecting the canvas I found that every canvas has object called 'data' , within data you can find the 'y' and 'z' , simple changed the z property name to my desired value :

```
cx2.data.z[color]=cx2.data.z.color
       delete cx2.data.z.color;
```

where 'color' on left side is a variable , but on right side was a string . Cheers.